# Dock control to other one in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have got MainForm with TabPage.
On TabPage i have got three groupboxes next to one another.
First is docked to left top, third to right top. everything is ok but if i maximize window , center textbox goes to bad position (is hide behing first groupbox) How dock this one to stay always between first and third groupbox?

Comment: What are you aiming for?  All 3 boxes to resize themselves to the same amount (or 1 and 3 fixed, with 2 expanding/shrinking?) - or something else?  Do you wish for re-sizing to apply to both vertical and horizontal axes?

Comment: @ne1410s I want to apply to both  vertical and horizontal axes

Comment: @ne1410s sorry i did with with anchor ! thanks

Comment: They are arranged in a horizontal row, correct?  Well vertical is straight-forward enough: make sure they are all `anchored` to both the top and the bottom of the form.  I'm struggling to think of the horizontal anchoring though... I can only suggest experimenting and seeing what happens.  As a last resort, you could always hook into the 'Form_SizeChanged' event and work something out dynamically.  Sorry thats not exactly definitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the Dock properties OR the anchor properties. Adding the groups boxes so they are ordered left to right:

**Using the Dock properties:**

```
`groupBox1.Dock = left`
`groupBox3.Dock = right`
`groupbox2.Dock = center`
```

**Using the Anchor properties:**

```
`groupBox1.Anchor = Top, Left`
`groupBox3.Anchor = Top, Right`
`groupbox2.Anchor = Top, Left, Right`
```

**EDIT:**
In either case the center groupBox (groupBox2) should adjust to fill the space between the two outer groupboxes (groupBox1 and groupBox3)